# How do I get the table header to align to top and stay at top?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I've got a virtualized table that I'm working on (using an example). How do I get the table header to line up correctly and also remain at the top of the table while scrolling

Code sandbox:-

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-table-virtualized-t2xkt

Comment: have you tried position fixed? https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_fixed

Comment: Did you search in the material-ui docs ? https://material-ui.com/components/tables/ ? there is a fixed header functionality https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#fixed-header . Reading the DOCs is the first thing you should do when using libraries

Comment: Use stickyHeader prop on the table

Answer (score 0):

I edited with new content: sorry i did not see the scrolling.
use in DataTable.js flex-direction: column:

```
  tableContent: {
    overflowY: "scroll",
    borderCollapse: "collapse",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column"
  },
```

and in the table head cells width 10%:

```
 tableCellHead: {
    fontSize: "1rem",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    border: "1px solid rgba(224, 224, 224, 1)",
    width:" 10%",
    "&:last-child": {
      paddingRight: "4px"
    }
  },

``
```

Comment: Removing flex means that they table can no longer be scrolled and the header disappeared

Comment: Nice! This is much closer but now the scroll bar is messed up and doesn't track correctly and I also appear to have two of them

Answer (score 0):

### Table header and body not lining up

This is caused by the `display: flex` used in the `.DataTable-tableContent-4` CSS class of your `<table>` element and in the inline style of your `<tbody>`. If you get rid of it, your table header and body will line up just as intended.

### Fixing your table scrollable-ness

In order to make your table scrollable, you defined an `height` and `overflow-y: scrollable`, that's the right thing to do but you did it on the wrong element.
Those CSS properties have to be on one of the the table container, any parent element of the table, not the table itself.

### Table header remaining at the top of the table while scrolling

You can use the `position: sticky` CSS attribute which, coupled to a `top: 0`, will let your header appear on top of your table while scrolling.

Here's a demo :

```css
.container {
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Reputation</td>
        <td>Meme potential</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Jon Skeet</td>
        <td>Far too much</td>
        <td>High</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td>Less that Jon Skeet</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Community</td>
        <td>-1</td>
        <td>Low</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Unknown</td>
        <td>Low</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Unknown</td>
        <td>Low</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Unknown</td>
        <td>Low</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Unknown</td>
        <td>Low</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Unknown</td>
        <td>Low</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Unknown</td>
        <td>Low</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Unknown</td>
        <td>Low</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Unknown</td>
        <td>Low</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Unknown</td>
        <td>Low</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        <td>Unknown</td>
        <td>Low</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

### EDIT :

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-table-virtualized-wg26b) is the corrected version of your code (Disclaimer: I am far from fluent in React, code correction was not done following React nor Material-UI best practices)

Comment: Removing flex doesn't solve the issue and makes the table no longer scrollable: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-table-virtualized-t2xkt

Comment: Feel free to fork and modify the sandbox :)

Comment: Is this what you're looking for ? https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-table-virtualized-l5x2u If it does, i'll edit my answer

Comment: No still doesn't work unfortunately. I just see a static table body without the header that can't be scrolled

Comment: Still not seeing the changes. I just see a table without a header that when you scroll the whole table just scrolls off the screen. Do you want to fork that sandbox and create your own one?

Comment: Working in Firefox but not in Chrome... It seems the problem comes from the abolute positionning and the `display` of your  `<tr>`, I'm looking into it

Comment: Ah you're a legend (yep I'm in chrome). Thank you so much for your help. I'm useless with CSS

Comment: Ok, the preview problem was due to absolute positionning of `<tr>` coupled to a manually-defined height of the table. I don't quite get why you did that but I removed it and hopefully this is what you are looking for : https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-table-virtualized-wg26b I'll edit my answer according to it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209065/discussion-between-oddrigue-and-bigbytes).